# Missing artifact bst-player-api:jar:2.0.3

Tags: eclipse, maven

as im trying mvn install on my project i get this : 
[WARNING] The POM for com.bramosystems.oss.player:bst-player-api:jar:2.0.3 is missing, no dependency information available.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myproject:myproject-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.bramosystems.oss.player:bst-player-api:jar:2.0.3 in http://repo.geosdi.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of geosdi.org has elapsed or updates are forced ->

my main pom :

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.bramosystems.oss.player</groupId>
                <artifactId>bst-player-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

myproject-web pom :

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.bramosystems.oss.player</groupId>
      <artifactId>bst-player-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

also in eclipse i have error shown on this dependency which says :

Missing artifact com.bramosystems.oss.player:bst-player-api:jar:2.0.3

i have no clue what to do..

Answer (score 0):

It is up again after my post. I had the same problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bst-player/onB1PNLc6kk